# Права доступа

Tags: ubuntu

Доброго времени суток! Такая проблема - установлен phpstorm ubuntu 12.04. Запущен под текущим пользователем(не под рутом). Когда пытаюсь закоммитить на гит, выдает ошибку  
error: open() permission denied. И когда просто пытаюсь удалить файл через ide не удаляет. В  чем может быть проблема?

Comment: На файл который не получается удалить ls -l /path/to/file , что скажет ?

Comment: Понял. Владелец www-data(создан php скриптом). Права rw-r--r--. В продолжение вопроса - можно настроить apache чтобы он создавал файлы с правами 770?

Comment: Да , это называется umask. Сделайте нужную настройку для вашего пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно запускаю апач на локальной машине от имени пользователя системы, делается это так:

В файле  /etc/apache2/envvars

Изменить:export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-dataexport APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

На: export APACHE_RUN_USER=usernameexport APACHE_RUN_GROUP=username

где username - ваше имя пользователя

Далее изменить права на каталог с проектом:

sudo chown -R username:username you_project

Далее перезапустить apache:

sudo service apache restart